# Why are my dynamic paint wave bake maps looking so weird?

Tags: uv, dynamic-paint

I'm working on a scene of rain falling onto a car. Now  I want the reflective shader's normal to be influenced by a dynamic wave displacement map, but when I bake the dynamic paint map I get these really weird patterns for some reason instead of smooth gradient like images. [image]

These are my settings

[image]

Am I doing something wrong? What setting should I change? Any alternative ideas for creating realistic rain drops on the car?

Thanks!

Comment: here are some images of the scene and the renders without the dynamic paint wave maps:
[scene](http://www.dumpt.com/img/links.php?file=e857r7h9ctm9hnu8blws.png)
[render 1](http://www.dumpt.com/img/links.php?file=fjps2fagm9agefl1x820.png)
[render 2](http://www.dumpt.com/img/links.php?file=rm9mx6btd5vkw4gb3tcf.png)
[render 3](http://www.dumpt.com/img/links.php?file=rm9mx6btd5vkw4gb3tcf.png)